# Why can't I find my variable in globals()?

Tags: python, loops, variables, global

I created a function to create a variable for random DNA. But when I want to look if `rdna` is in `globals()` I get `False` as result

```
from random import choice
def randomseq():
  global rdna
  rdna=""
  largo = int(input("Sequence Length: "))
  for count in range(largo):
    rdna+=choice("CGTA")
  return rdna
```

```
rdna in globals()
False
```

Why can't I get `True`?

Comment: First of all, you need to call the function so that `globals()` is populated with the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example:

```
x = 1
my_var = 'x'
print(my_var in globals())
```

This prints `True`, but not because `my_var` is a global variable, but because `x` is. `globals()` returns a dictionary with all global variables and their values, `my_var in globals()` in this case is the same as asking `'x' in globals()`.

You want this:

```
'rdna' in globals()
```

Answer (score 1):

`rdna in globals()` will search for the value stored in the variable `rdna` in `globals()`. If you literally want to search for `"rdna"` you should make it a string literal:

```
"rdna" in globals()
```